# Typescript: How to determine if string variable is in enum?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes 1 argument `wallet_type_id` that could either be of type `FOOBAR_ACCOUNT_TYPES` or `PRETAX_ACCOUNT_TYPES`. I'm trying to create a function to return a boolean for when the `wallet_type_id` is of type `PRETAX_ACCOUNT_TYPES`, but my code doesn't work as expected.

```
enum FOOBAR_ACCOUNT_TYPES {
  WELLNESS = 'wellness',
  REWARDS = 'rewards',
}

enum PRETAX_ACCOUNT_TYPES {
  TRANSIT = 'transit',
  PARKING = 'parking',
  FSA = 'fsa',
}

const isPretaxAccount = (
  wallet_type_id: FOOBAR_ACCOUNT_TYPES | PRETAX_ACCOUNT_TYPES
) => wallet_type_id in PRETAX_ACCOUNT_TYPES;

console.log("should be false: ", isPretaxAccount(FOOBAR_ACCOUNT_TYPES.WELLNESS)); // returns false
console.log("should be true: ", isPretaxAccount(PRETAX_ACCOUNT_TYPES.FSA)); // returns false <--- WRONG
```

Why is the 2nd console log statement not returning true?

Typescript Playground link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYg8nAQgQQEoH1kGEtwKoByAKukQJoAKAogMpQDeAUFFAOpUAyHBtdAvFADkAd2AAbMSGABnaYIA0zKKiqs0AEX5CATsGEBDbQBM5igL6NGoSFAoqiyABqYc+YqUq0GSoqmQEaAEkiKAFBABdtfRBpAEtwhSUKNABpQIIAcVChAAdDAGtYkABzRJYYGmRswQAzaX1Ei0YAYwB7GPCoWOkKXXD9AA9kZrawEE6BAAolAwlgcPRwgE8c4HRYowAuWAQUDGxcQhJyajoAH1t7JxdD9xPaRgBKUIA+KFmxecWVtY2ukEuVAczgObmOnhoAG5LG0Yq1PgA6MStYqTABE0gAFq0wGIjFAAEbAKA1fRiaTAbZo+RdHp9QbDUbjSbwJBoG5gjynBHsLg8Gg0R6PaGw6Tw4BIlHorE4vGE4mRMCUqDU2m9eYMkY45l2IHXUFHLm0BEVZBCyFAA

Comment: You're looking at keys and not values.  You can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJyYlm) or something like it instead.